# Vk api - перестал работать бот по непонятным причинам

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

У меня был написан бот для вк. Работает на хостинге smart ape.
Но сегодня я заметил, что он перестал отвечать на сообщения (причём до этого бот работал 2 недели)
Я сразу стал проверять работу хостинга - работает
Потом в index.php написал `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))` - выводит запрос, то есть здесь всё работает
Потом я проверил, что код доходит до места, где уже отправляется ответ

```js
$request_params = [
  'user_id' => $data - > object - > user_id,
  'message' => 'message',
  'access_token' => get_env_var('VK_TOKEN'),
  'v' => '5.80'
];

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'.http_build_query($request_params));
```

тут тоже всё вроде в порядке.
В vk при нажатии кнопки "проверить" - всё окей.
Что здесь не так?

Comment: Откуда нам знать что не так? Пробуйте через curl отправлять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, версия 5.80 больше не поддерживается. На текущий момент актуальна версия не ниже 5.81.

> Обратите внимание!
>
> - С 19 августа 2021 года срок жизни версий ниже 5.41 закончится.
> - С 26 августа 2021 года перестанут поддерживаться версии ниже 5.61.
> - С 2 сентября 2021 года прекратится поддержка версий ниже 5.81.

[Подробнее](https://vk.com/dev/constant_version_updates)